# Grouped rank number sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table like

```
  ID |  Name  |  Rank
    1  Name1  
    2  Name2  
    1  Name3  
    2  Name4  
    3  Name5  
    1  Name6
    1  Name7
```

My result should be this:

```
  ID |  Name  |  Rank
    1  Name1     1
    2  Name2     1 
    1  Name3     2
    2  Name4     2 
    3  Name5     1 
    1  Name6     3
    1  Name7     4
```

I found this: Rank over(order by name) but it will rank the whole table. How do I do a rank grouped by ID?

UPDATE:

I'm sorry guys. Michael Ames provided perfectly right answer. But I need the same thing with WHERE condition. I misinterpreted the question and I'm sorry. The real question is this: 
So I need to rank all names where Client is not null order by Name Group by ID.
I have these tables:

```
   ID |  Name  |  Client | Rank
        1  Name1  Client1
        2  Name2  NULL
        1  Name3  Client2
        2  Name4  Client3
        3  Name5  Client4
        1  Name6  NULL
        1  Name7  Client5
```

My result should be this:

```
      ID |  Name |  Client | Rank
        1  Name1  Client1     1
        2  Name2  NULL
        1  Name3  Client2     2
        2  Name4  Client3     1
        3  Name5  Client4     1
        1  Name6  NULL        
        1  Name7  Client5     3
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want the "rank" numbers to be... where do the 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4 values come from?

Comment: How do I do a rank grouped by ID? Like. I have 4 items with Id "1". So I need to rank them 1,2,3,4

Comment: How do you want to rank them? By first-come-first-serve when ordered by `Name`? Also, should the results be added to the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy peasy:

The following example ranks each name, grouped by their ID:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Name ASC) as Rank
FROM Names
ORDER BY Name ASC
```

The following example ranks each name, grouped by their ID, but skipping records where Client is null:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Client, Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Name ASC) as Rank
FROM Names 
WHERE Client IS NOT NULL
```

And finally, the following example uses the results from the previous example to update the table with the appropriate ranks:

```
UPDATE Names 
SET Rank = ranks.rank
FROM
  (SELECT ID, Name, Client, Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Name ASC) as Rank
  FROM Names 
  WHERE Client IS NOT NULL
  ) ranks
WHERE Names.Name = ranks.Name
```

On the last example, if Name is not unique, you'll very likely want to change the WHERE clause to match on a unique identifier.

Some reasonably comprehensible documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: Please see updates: 
I'm sorry guys. Michael Ames provided perfectly right answer. But I need the same thing with WHERE condition. I misinterpreted the question and I'm sorry. The real question is this: 
So I need to rank all names where Client is not null order by Name Group by ID.

Comment: Is your ultimate goal to return the records you show in your desired output?  Or to update the table?

Comment: My ultimate record is to update, but I can do an insert from one table to another using select statement (I'm using table parameters), so it doesn't matter. Does it answer your question?

Comment: In other words, do you need a SELECT statement that returns all the rows, including where Client IS NULL?  Or do you just need an UPDATE statement that updates the rows where Client IS NOT NULL?  Both are possible, but somewhat different.

Comment: Do you have a primary key on the table?

Comment: It is very flexible.I do not have an Id but I can insert an Id if needed and I also can do both select or update whatever is easier.

Comment: Done (assuming I understand your question!)

Comment: That is awesome. The one with update worked great! Thanks a lot.